# How to echo two strings added together into one column inside the database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

It seems like an odd question but here it goes. How do I add two strings together in order for them to appear as one inside the database ?

`<input type="hidden" name="user" value ="<?php  echo  $articless['name'] . " " .  $user_data->id;  ?>" />`

This does not work. My desired outcome is to add them together so they appear as two words added together in a column without spaces for example: articlebox. Is it the . " " . between two variables that needs adjusting ?

Comment: the concept is correct. So something else seems to be wrong. When you say "not working", what are you experiencing? Can you please elaborate a bit further?

Comment: When changed to "not null" for the column. The form dissapears completely showing blank. When "not null" is unselected, everything else is added to the database except for that line.

Comment: Is a regular post or are you using ajax? Sometimes seralizeArray or serialize methods in jquery ignore hidden inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the " ". You combine string using the dot (.) only.

```
<input type="hidden" name="user" value ="<?php  echo  $articless['name'].$user_data->id;  ?>" />
```